# Use for loop to write to many files in c++

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to write data to a 100 files `gnu_2D_t0_Q_xt_2sol_anal.dat`, `gnu_2D_t1_Q_xt_2sol_anal.dat`, ..., `gnu_2D_t100_Q_xt_2sol_anal.dat`. Using [this question](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/111453-creating-files-in-for-loops/) as inspiration, I've come up with the following snippet of code

```
int m = 100;
for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
{
    stringstream aa;    // http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/
    aa << k;
    filename = "gnu_2D_t" + aa.str() + "_Q_xt_2sol_anal.dat";
    files.open(filename.c_str());  // http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/122208/
    for(int i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
    {
        files << x_begin + (i * h) << setw(18);
        files << Q_xt_matrix[i][t_matrix[m]] << setw(18);
        files << endl;
    }
    files.close;
}
```

However, it yields the following error

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function files.close;
                                                            ^
```

Does anybody what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `close` is a function. Use `files.close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close` is a method, not a member of `files`. Change the last line to `files.close()`.

Comment: Oh of course thank you, I feel very silly now. I will accept your answer once I'm allowed.